# When to split a large table

Tags: database-design, partitioning, insert, sybase-sql-anywhere

I run the SQL Anywhere DBMS, and we have a table of about 10 columns(normal text, timestamps etc).
However, in my use-case, every single day, the table gets **2160000** new rows.
It's also crucial that new inserts to the db takes less than 3ms.

I'm in the design phase, so the database isnt in use yet.
Question is, should I put everything into one table?
Or should I design my system from the start to use multiple tables, divided by for instance days? (Will this improve performance, since I'm having smaller tables?)

Comment: Inserting 1500 rows per second, 24 hours per day, will be you main issue. After you solve this, you can start dealing with how your DBMS will handle the big table (+45G rows per year) and the queries you want to run against it and if partitioning per day or month or whatever is worth.

Comment: Thanks, actually I did a tiny bit of calculation error. The number is 400 rows per second. 216 0000 rows over a timespan of 90 minutes(roughly every day). So 400 per second, not  1500. Anyway I know I can insert fast enough, that's not the issue.

Comment: If insert performance is not the issue, then you need to define what you mean when you say: _Will this improve performance..._ performance in what context? What kind of operations will you need to do?

Comment: Well, ok, let me put it this way: Insert performance is no issue at the moment. But in general, how many rows is needed before you could notice substantial drop in insert time?